# Do combination OR and AND statements work with Facebook's FQL?

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

I'm attempting to execute a semi-advanced query using Facebook's FQL.

```
SELECT message FROM stream WHERE actor_id= userid_1 AND source_id=userid_2 OR actor_id=userid_2 AND source_id=userid_1
```

Everytime I run it though, it comes up blank, even though there are posts between the two users on their walls, so this possible or do I need to use some sort of alternative method?

Answer (score 2):

It should work  with the combination. Why dont you try with enclosing proper brackets like

SELECT message FROM stream WHERE actor_id= userid_1 AND (source_id=userid_2 OR actor_id=userid_2) AND source_id=userid_1